# monitor the number of k8s pod's tcp connections

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Lately I have problem with Pods in k8s. The k8s Node hang caused by too many tcp connections,But I don't know which container caused it.I want to know how to monitor the number of k8s pod's tcp connections,thanks

Answer (score 1):

In **kubernetes** there is no such built-in metric. But you can find it in kubernetes addons, called Service Mesh like [Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/) *Client/Server Telemetry Reporting* feature provides `istio_tcp_connections_opened_total` which can be exported to **Prometheus**.